# segfault with mod_wsgi / mod_python after Python upgrade on Gentoo

Tags: apache-2.2, gentoo, mod-wsgi, mod-python, segmentation-fault

I'm having a problem after upgrading from Python 2.5 to 2.6

I'm using Gentoo and running a Django app with Apache 2 and mod_python.
After the upgrade I started getting a segfault when I try to access the site, Apache starts fine and can serve static pages.

I've tried moving the site to mod_wsgi and still get the segfault. I've tried reinstalling Apache, Apr, mod_python, mod_wsgi. I've tried revdep-rebuild, python-updater. I've removed Python 2.5 from the system.
The site works when I run it from Django's development server.

I'm lost, I just don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues 
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues 
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp

Various reasons for crashes are documented and also pointers to how to configure Apache/mod_wsgi to get more logging etc about what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I've found the problem.

It was pysco, I forgot I had it installed and was imported by my site. I removed it and everything works now.

I've used gdb to find out. Thanks for your help.